# Making hibernate project with spring-rest

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to make a simple spring rest project with hibernate.

I have made DAO and service layer. I have also configured beans in dispatcher-servlet and autowired in controller class with service and in service DAO session factory and transactions.

But I am continuously getting errors.

I have also uploaded  a photo of error.

```
dispatcher-servlet.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<!--    <mvc:annotation-driven />  -->

<!--    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />  -->

<!--JDBC ko properties-->
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"  
         destroy-method="close">  
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />  
    <beans:property name="url"  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student_database" />  
    <beans:property name="username" value="root" />  
    <beans:property name="password" value="" />  
</beans:bean>  

<!-- Hibernate ko SessionFactory Bean definition part -->  
<beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"  
         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
<!--        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">  
        <beans:list>  
            <beans:value>com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven.bean</beans:value>  
        </beans:list>  
    </beans:property>  -->
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <beans:props>  
            <beans:prop      key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect  
            </beans:prop>  
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>  
        </beans:props>  
    </beans:property>  
</beans:bean>  

<context:component-scan base-    package="com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven.controller"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>  

<beans:bean id="transactionManager"      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">  
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />  
</beans:bean>
```

```
controller class:
package com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven.controller;
/* I have not included imports*/
@RestController
public class StudentController {

@Autowired
ServiceLayer studentService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers =   "Accept=application/json")
public void insert(@RequestBody Student student) {
    studentService.insert(student);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers =  "Accept=application/json")
public void update(@RequestBody Student student) {
    studentService.update(student);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/delete", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") int id) {
    studentService.delete(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers =  "Accept=application/json")
public List<Student> getAll() {

    List<Student> listOfStudent = studentService.getAll();
    return listOfStudent;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/searchById/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,   headers = "Accept=application/json")
public Student searchById(@PathVariable int id) {
    return studentService.searchById(id);
}
}

This is my service layer implementation:

package com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven.Service;

@Service("studentService")
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceLayer {

@Autowired StudentDAO studentDao;

@Transactional
@Override
public void insert(Student s) {
    studentDao.insert(s);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void update(Student s) {
    studentDao.update(s);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void delete(int id) {
    studentDao.delete(id);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public List<Student> getAll() {
    return studentDao.getAll();
}

@Transactional
@Override
public Student searchById(int id) {
    return studentDao.searchById(id);
}

}

This is my DAO implementation:

package com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven.DAO;

@Repository
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private Session session;
private Transaction trans;

@Override
public void insert(Student s) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    trans = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(s);
    trans.commit();
    session.close();
}

@Override
public void update(Student s) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    trans = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(s);
    trans.commit();
    session.close();
}

@Override
public void delete(int id) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    trans = session.beginTransaction();
    Student sObject = (Student) session.get(Student.class, id);
    session.delete(sObject);
    trans.commit();
    session.close();
}

@Override
public List<Student> getAll() {
    return session.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student s").list();
}

@Override
public Student searchById(int id) {
    return (Student) session.get(Student.class, id);
}


}
```

I am getting this error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: couldn't see your error!

Comment: The error says that spring could not find a bean of type ServiceLayer.

Comment: Change the component scan base to com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven. With your current config it couldnt find the Beans which are not in the controller package

Answer (score 0):

Change your configuration

```
<context:component-scan base-    package="com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven.controller"/>
```

To

```
<context:component-scan base-    package="com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven"/>
```

Then Spring scans all your classes beneath the SpringRestMaven package and creates beans from the annotated classes.

In your current configuration Spring only scans and creates beans from beneath the .controller package. Your ServiceLayer isn't in this package and therefore Spring couldn't find the class, doesn't create a bean and could not autowire the field.

Comment: Thank you sir, I did you you asked for. In fact I had done it previously only but I was getting this error please have a look:

Comment: Severe:   Exception while loading the app :  .ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'webController' for bean class [com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven.WebController] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.mycompany.SpringRestMaven.controller.WebController]

Comment: Well looks like you have two classes named `WebController` (in different packages)?